# Can I create a top navigation menu like desktop app using ionic framework

Tags: drop-down-menu, ionic-framework, navbar

I am new to Ionic and I am up to creating a desktop site using Ionic (I understand Ionic is meant for Mobile apps). What I am trying to achieve is to create a top menu more on the lines of bootstrap. But, I see that I can add my menus only on the sides (left & right while the center area is meant for the title). How can I achieve a top-horizontal menu bar using Ionic. Any help or direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark ">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
                <i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>  
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons  side="right" style="width: calc(100% - 60px);">
                <label class="item item-input transparentBack noBorder" style="padding-left:1px;margin-right:12px">
                  <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon  "></i>
                  <input ng-click="runHashTagSearch('#-1')" type="text" class="navSearchHolder" placeholder="search in " >
                </label>
                <div style="width: 110px;margin-top: 11px;">
                  <span ui-sref="messagesHome"    style="width:auto;display: inline;"  >
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-email" style="font-size: 24px;padding: 6px;     "> </i>

                  </span>
                  <span style="width:auto;display: inline;"   ng-click="goToStateAnimated()">
                    <i class="icon ion-android-notifications" style="font-size: 24px;padding: 6px;"> </i>

                  </span>
                </div> 
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
```